# How to prevent H2 standalone command line creating new database?

Tags: h2

I start a H2 database in standalone mode like this:

```
java -cp "h2-1.4.182.jar;%H2DRIVERS%;%CLASSPATH%" org.h2.tools.Server -web -webAllowOthers -tcp -tcpAllowOthers -browser
```

Whenever I log into the H2 with Hibernate or a Web-Console a new Database can be created if I use a new name.

I know it's possible to prevent such a behavior by the connection url by adding just ";IFEXISTS=TRUE", but can I do the same in command lines for the standalone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the command line option `-ifExists`. See also the Javadoc and the command line help for the server.